# Lines on Maps Connecting to Longitud 0 Latitud 0

Tags: r, plot, plotly

I want to create a flight path map using plotly. When following the plotly tutorial called 'Lines on Maps', I do not get the expected output. While all flight paths are indeed drawn, for some reason, a lot of lines seems to connect to the origin (longitude==0, latitude==0). [image: Picture showing the problem here]. What is wrong?

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
# airport locations
air <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_february_us_airport_traffic.csv')
# flights between airports
flights <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_february_aa_flight_paths.csv')
flights$id <- seq_len(nrow(flights))

# map projection
geo <- list(
  scope = 'world',
  projection = list(type = 'azimuthal equal area'),
  showland = TRUE,
  landcolor = toRGB("gray95"),
  countrycolor = toRGB("gray80")
)

p <- plot_geo(locationmode = 'USA-states', color = I("red")) %>%
  add_markers(
    data = air, x = ~long, y = ~lat, text = ~airport,
    size = ~cnt, hoverinfo = "text", alpha = 0.5
  ) %>%
  add_segments(
    data = group_by(flights, id),
    x = ~start_lon, xend = ~end_lon,
    y = ~start_lat, yend = ~end_lat,
    alpha = 0.3, size = I(1), hoverinfo = "none"
  ) %>%
  layout(
    title = 'Feb. 2011 American Airline flight paths<br>(Hover for airport names)',
    geo = geo, showlegend = FALSE, height=800
  )

ggplotly(p)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I notice that `add_paths` does not have options for x and xend, nor y and yend, unlike `add_segments`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split` argument with your `id` variable to stop drawing between each line of you data.frame :

```
  add_segments(
    data = group_by(flights, id),
    x = ~start_lon, xend = ~end_lon,
    y = ~start_lat, yend = ~end_lat, split=~id,
    alpha = 0.3, size = I(1), hoverinfo = "none"
  ) %>%
```

[image]